# How to pass Firebase Authentication state from native Swift code to React Native view

Tags: swift, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

We have an app built in Swift that we're porting (in part) to React Native. Users/Authentication is powered by Firebase.

In our new flow, we're having users authenticate with Firebase via native Swift code. When authenticated, we load the React Native view.

**Problem:** React Native doesn't know anything about the authentication state. I can pass props (like a uid) from Swift to React Native, but big whoop - I can't do anything with Firebase. Maybe I'm missing something?

**Question:** Is there a way to generate a Firebase auth token in Swift and pass that token to React Native to authenticate the user? Note - I know about custom auth tokens and the admin SDK for server-side authentication, but that's not the ideal solution. I'd like to log in via Swift, generate a Firebase auth token (in Swift), hand that token to React Native, authenticate/log in the Firebase user (in Javascript).